# multiple page print formatting using react to print overlaps contents in footer and header of second page

Tags: reactjs

Iam using React js  react-to-print If contents are more then footer overlapping in page content

[image: content overlaping]

Comment: Have you tried viewing this in another browser / saving as PDF and viewing it in a PDF viewer? Just to rule out that it isn't an issue with Edge's print preview

Comment: Please, add more details in your question.

Comment: @Shameen Yes, I  tried different browser but results are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution By using html table and the over lapping content with page footer is solved by the css code It is Mentioned in the code section.

```
<table>
            <thead><tr><td>
              <div class="header-space"> </div>
            </td></tr></thead>
            <tbody><tr><td>
              <div class="content">...</div>
            </td></tr></tbody>
            <tfoot><tr><td>
              <div class="footer-space"> </div>
            </td></tr></tfoot>
          </table>
          <div class="header">...</div>
          <div class="footer">...</div>

          // CSS
          .header, .header-space,
          .footer, .footer-space {
            height: 100px;
          }
          .header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
          }
          .footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
          }
```